# Is it possible to link two or more adatpers on the same ArrayList<T> and show different subsets

Tags: java, android, object, adapter

maybe I have a strange question today. I already "solved" this at the moment by using two lists, but I want the infos in only one list, because i think it is easier to maintain and cleaner.

Lets assume that we have an object called

```
public class PersonsInfo{
int Age;
String Name;
Booelan Female;
}
```

a list holding all the peoples info

```
List<PersonsInfo> coolPeople = new ArrayList<PersonsInfo>()
```

and two Views, a `GridView` and a `ListView`

Now I want to show the girls in the `GridView` and the guys in the `ListView`.

Is this possible and what do i have to do, that this works? I don't get it anymore :(

Or is my solution with two lists the only one?

Greetings!

Comment: easier to maintain and cleaner will be database and 2xCursors instead of 1 or 2 lists ... it is possible to do this with one list but you have to implement your own ArrayAdapter which will be really, really complicated ( you can use the same adapter class but not the same instance (coz fx.: one adapter instance should return count of girls and second guys, ...) so one instance of array but 2 instances of addapter or even 2 different adapters

Comment: Hi Selvin, thanks for your answer.. for the most situations a little too much, but I think to store people infos the optimal solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a LINQ equivalent in java, but you will need to look at [Quaere here](http://quaere.codehaus.org/)
This will allow you to filter girls / boys based on the `boolean` property you have in your class.